# Bacula Backup - Add a second partition to write files to

Tags: backup, bacula

I would like to set up bacula - well, my first steps have been successful.

All my backups are written to /bacula/backup. But / has only 900GB. So I want bacula to write to /sdb1/bacula/backup, too. /sdb1 has another 950GB of space. The sum of available backup-space should be 1850GB HDD:

Well, I got the following config of /etc/bacula/bacula-sd.conf:

```
Storage {                             # definition of myself
  Name = backup-sd
  SDPort = 9103                  # Director's port
  WorkingDirectory = "/var/lib/bacula"
  Pid Directory = "/var/run/bacula"
  Maximum Concurrent Jobs = 20
  SDAddress = backup.example.com
}

Director {
  Name = backup-dir
  Password = "doyoureallywanttoknow"
}
Device {
  Name = FileStorage
  Media Type = File
  Archive Device = /bacula/backup
  LabelMedia = yes;                   # lets Bacula label unlabeled media
  Random Access = Yes;
  AutomaticMount = yes;               # when device opened, read it
  RemovableMedia = no;
  AlwaysOpen = no;
}
```

Okay - now I would like to add another device. I guess I could just add a second entry like this:

```
Device {
  Name = FileStorage
  Media Type = File
  Archive Device = /sdb1/bacula/backup
  LabelMedia = yes;                   # lets Bacula label unlabeled media
  Random Access = Yes;
  AutomaticMount = yes;               # when device opened, read it
  RemovableMedia = no;
  AlwaysOpen = no;
}
```

?

Do I have to change something else so that bacula is able to write more than 900GB - if the first 900GB are "full" it should switch to the second hdd.

Comment: I have not the time right now to a proper answer, but it seems to me that http://sourceforge.net/projects/vchanger/ vchanger is a solution to your problem

Comment: Hi there, is there any difference between vchanger and the built-in virtual auto changer?

Comment: from http://blog.bacula.org/whitepapers/CommunityDiskBackup.pdf:`The situation is a bit more complicated if you want to treat two different physical
disk drives (or partitions) logically as a single drive, which Bacula does not directly
support.` therefore i mentioned vchanger. The by bacula distributed disk-changer script is more appropiate to your situation I think.